# How can i change the currency format in SQL Server?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, currency-formatting

I have a column called currency which I am retrieve from SQL Server. 
The column contains 1234567.789456

I want to show this in 1,234,567.789456
I just want to show the currency in comma separated form only in price column.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format at the client using PHP's `number_format()` function ([thanks @karthikr for the link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)). PHP is more than capable of adding thousands separators to numbers; it is much more expensive to ask SQL Server to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. I can use it like
number_format(1,234,567.789456)